# Why do Samsung phones render musical symbols (U+266D-F) incorrectly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm working on a simple pitch pipe app and I can't figure out why Samsung phones are rendering sharps and flats incorrectly. I fixed the previous issue that I asked earlier with general fonts not fitting; this is a Samsung-specific issue. Here's a picture of what I'm dealing with (Galaxy S7, Marshmallow 6.0.1):
[image: S7 Photo]

Whereas this is what it should look like (Nexus 6 Emulator, Marshmallow 6.0.1):

[image: Emulator Photo]

The same problem occurs on a Galaxy S4 I tested. Notice how the musical symbols on the Samsung device are black and 3D-looking and they have too much spacing. What is causing this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Which font are you using? Custom, Roboto, Droid Sans?

Comment: In XML I have declared the font as "sans-serif-light", so it uses the default for Android, which I believe is Roboto.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use png images to have the same view on all devices. Different devices can show emojis different. For example check [this link](http://emojipedia.org/regional-indicator-symbol-letter-e/) for see variation of symbol  (U+1F1EA).